# Mapping pandas column by matching substrings from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mapping

I have a dataframe containing names and a list of dictionaries with names and counts for each name. I need to create a new column based on the presence of each name in the `results`. But the problem is not exact match but partial based on first names only. All the solutions I tried so far are very clumsy so I'm hopping this wonderful community may suggest something more elegant.

```
dic = {"IDs": ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','k','l','m'],
       "names": ['Ailbhe Yowa',
 'Hannah Kirst',
 'Morris Hunt',
 'Flavia Quor in the UK',
 'Sarah Smith and Alexandra Libman',
 'Flavia Morris, Mark Torre, Ann Moor',
 'Rowena Freez',
 'Adam Lion in USA',
 'Mahmood Jade  in Europe',
 'Morris Tool and  Francois Lopin']
    
}
test = pd.DataFrame(dic)

results = [[{'name': 'Ailbhe', 'count': 17}],
 [{'name': 'Mahmood', 'count': 2818}],
 [{'name': 'Debbie', 'count': 11493}],
 [{'name': 'Arthur', 'count': 20587}],
 [{'name': 'Clive', 'count': 2703}],
 [{'name': 'Flavia', 'count': 10166}],
 [{'name': 'Alexandra', 'count': 1939}],
 [{'name': 'Sarah', 'count': 88388}],
 [{'name': 'Morris', 'count': 3194}],
 [{'name': 'Cameron', 'count': 3334}]]
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
    IDs names                               results
0   a   Ailbhe Yowa                         [{'name': 'Ailbhe', 'count': 17}]
1   b   Hannah Kirst    
2   c   Morris Hunt                         [{'name': 'Morris', 'count': 3194}]
3   d   Flavia Quor in the UK               [{'name': 'Flavia', 'count': 10166}]
4   e   Sarah Smith and Alexandra Libman    [{'name': 'Sarah', 'count': 88388}, {'name': 'Alexandra', 'count': 1939}]
5   f   Flavia Morris, Mark Torre, Ann Moor [{'name': 'Flavia', 'count': 10166}]
6   g   Rowena Freez    
7   k   Adam Lion in USA    
8   l   Mahmood Jade in Europe              [{'name': 'Mahmood', 'count': 2818}]
9   m   Morris Tool and Francois Lopin      [{'name': 'Morris', 'count': 3194}]
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed this. I updated the output now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.findall`:

```
name_dict = {l[0]["name"]: l[0] for l in results}
reg = "(%s)" % "|".join(list(name_dict))
test["results"] = test["names"].str.findall(reg).apply(lambda x: [name_dict[i] for i in x])
print(test)
```

Output:

```
  IDs                                names  \
0   a                          Ailbhe Yowa   
1   b                         Hannah Kirst   
2   c                          Morris Hunt   
3   d                Flavia Quor in the UK   
4   e     Sarah Smith and Alexandra Libman   
5   f  Flavia Morris, Mark Torre, Ann Moor   
6   g                         Rowena Freez   
7   k                     Adam Lion in USA   
8   l              Mahmood Jade  in Europe   
9   m      Morris Tool and  Francois Lopin   

                                             results  
0                  [{'name': 'Ailbhe', 'count': 17}]  
1                                                 []  
2                [{'name': 'Morris', 'count': 3194}]  
3               [{'name': 'Flavia', 'count': 10166}]  
4  [{'name': 'Sarah', 'count': 88388}, {'name': '...  
5  [{'name': 'Flavia', 'count': 10166}, {'name': ...  
6                                                 []  
7                                                 []  
8               [{'name': 'Mahmood', 'count': 2818}]  
9                [{'name': 'Morris', 'count': 3194}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resultsToAdd = []
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    for result_row in results:
        isFound = False
        for result in result_row:
                if result['name'] in row['names']:
                    isFound = True
                    break
        if isFound:
            break
    if isFound:
        resultsToAdd.append(result_row)
    else :
        resultsToAdd.append(" ")
test["results"] = resultsToAdd        
print(test)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I have multiple names. For row 4 the output contains only Alexandra.